# Having extreme difficulty with determining the correct value type for std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, types, stdmap, php-cpp

<sup>**Addendum:**</sup>

Let me simplify my question, to try this one step at a time, because I feel I've created too much confusion about what I'm trying to achieve.

<sup>Mind you, I'm using C++11 and I think I'm bound to using this when using the PHP-CPP library. But, as I'm a total beginner, I'm not even sure about this.</sup>

My ultimate goal would be to "simply" create a map that can hold *any* value that the template `Php::Class` returns. But let's just start by trying a concrete one, for instance `Php::Class<Animal::Mammal>`.

First, I create a class in the namespace `Animal` called `Mammal`, which extends from `Php::Base` (when you want to export a class to PHP with PHP-CPP, it needs to extend `Php::Base`):

```
namespace Animal {
  class Mammal : public Php::Base { /* left out for brevity */ }
}
```

Then, to keep it simple, let me just try to create a map inside `get_module()` for now and just try to add an element there:

```
extern "C"
{
  PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module() {    
    // create the map
    std::map<std::string, Php::Class<Animal::Mammal>> classMap;

    // create the thing (at this point I just don't know what the actual return type is anymore) that will be exported later on.
    Php::Class<Animal::Mammal> mammal( "Mammal" );

    // try to add this "thing" to the map:
    classMap[ "Animal::Mammal" ] = mammal;

    /* left out for brevity */
}
```

This results in:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Php::Class<Animal::Mammal>&
       Php::Class<Animal::Mammal>::operator=(const Php::Class<Animal::Mammal>&)’
```

When I try:

```
// require a pointer
std::map<std::string, Php::Class<Animal::Mammal>*> classMap;

classMap[ "Animal::Mammal" ] = *mammal;
```

This results in:

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘Php::Class<Animal::Mammal>’)
```

I've tried numerous other things as well, but nothing seem to allow me to put whatever the template `Php::Class` creates into the map. I'm pulling my hair out, at this point. What am I missing?

Is it perhaps that the template `Php::Class` creates something that simply cannot be put in a map? How do I find out what the thing is that the template `Php::Class` actually creates?

---

<sup>**Original question:**</sup>

Although I have some cursory knowledge of C++, I'm new to actually programming with it.

I'm trying to develop a PHP extension with [PHP-CPP](http://www.php-cpp.com/). With this library you're able to define C++ classes and export them as PHP classes. [Their documentation](http://www.php-cpp.com/documentation) almost exclusively shows [examples](http://www.php-cpp.com/documentation/classes-and-objects) where you export those classes and methods inside it's main `get_module()` function.

However, as this could get rather cluttered pretty quickly, I'd like to move this logic close to the individual classes instead. So, I've created a template function for this:

```
namespace Animal
{
  template<typename T>
  void addToExtension( Php::Extension &extension, Php::Namespace &ns, ClassMap &map ) { }
}
```

Which I then specialize with something like:

```
namespace Animal
{
  class Mammal : public Php::Base
  {
  };

  template<>
  inline void addToExtension<Mammal>( Php::Extension &extension, Php::Namespace &ns, ClassMap &map ) {
    Php::Class<Mammal> clss( "Mammal" );

    // this is where I'm having extreme difficulty with
    map[ "Animal::Mammal" ] = clss;

    // add class to namespace
    ns.add( std::move( clss ) );
  }
}
```

...and in `get_module()` I then do this:

```
PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module() {
  static Php::Extension extension( "animals", "0.1" );

  Php::Namespace ns( "Animal" );

  Animal::ClassMap classMap;

  Animal::addToExtension<Animal::Mammal>( extension, ns, classMap );
  Animal::addToExtension<Animal::Dog>( extension, ns, classMap );
  Animal::addToExtension<Animal::Cat>( extension, ns, classMap );
etc...

  extension.add( std::move( ns ) );

  return extension;
}
```

As you can see, I want to add each individual class to the `Animal::ClassMap` map as well, because I want to use these when subsequent classes need to extend from them (for the export to PHP, that is):

```
// for instance, something like (not sure yet, if this is actually possible)
clss.extends( map[ "Animal::Mammal" ] );
```

But this is what I'm having extreme difficulties with. I've tried to define `Animal::ClassMap` in all sorts of manners:

```
namespace Animal
{
  // some examples of what I've tried:
  typedef std::map<std::string, Php::Class> ClassMap;
  typedef std::map<std::string, Php::Class*> ClassMap;
  typedef std::map<std::string, Php::Base> ClassMap;
  typedef std::map<std::string, Php::Base*> ClassMap;
  typedef std::map<std::string, Php::ClassBase> ClassMap;
  typedef std::map<std::string, Php::ClassBase*> ClassMap;
  typedef std::map<std::string, Php::Class<Php::Base>> ClassMap;
  typedef std::map<std::string, Php::Class<Php::Base>*> ClassMap;
  typedef std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Php::Class>> ClassMap;
  // etc., etc., etc. ...
}
```

and tried to assign to it in all sorts of manners as well:

```
Php::Class<Mammal> clss( "Mammal" );

// some examples of what I've tried:
map[ "Animal::Mammal" ] = clss;
map[ "Animal::Mammal" ] = *clss;
map[ "Animal::Mammal" ] = &clss;
map[ "Animal::Mammal" ] = std::make_shared<Php::Class>( clss );
map[ "Animal::Mammal" ] = std::make_shared<Php::ClassBase>( clss );

map.insert( std::pair<std::string, Php::Class>( "Animal::Mammal", clss ) );
// etc., etc., etc. ...
```

but nothing compiles.

I've gotten compile errors ranging from "`operator*` not defined", to "incomplete class" (or something to that effect), to "template argument is invalid".

As you can see, I clearly lack an actual understanding of what needs to be done here.

How do I determine what the proper value type for the map should be and how do I then properly add a "class" (is it even a proper class?) to the map?

---

<sup>PS: I'm fairly confident I've correctly included all necessary headers/files in the appropriate files. I've just omitted those in my examples for brevity.</sup>

Comment: `map` is a `ClassMap` not a `std::map`, or is it just a typedef?

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, see the second last code block, where I've tried to typedef it in all sorts of ways.

Comment: oh i see. The thing is you only have values of the same type in a map. Maybe a `std::variant` or `std::any` can help (though I never used them myself, so my suggestion might be completely off)

Comment: @user463035818 I think I've actually tried those as well, but I might be mistaken. I'll try it once more.

Comment: @user463035818 It appears `std::any` and `std::variant` are C++17 features, but I'm using C++11. I'm not sure if I could just switch to C++17. But before resorting to those, I'd actually like to know if there's a less generic options available, as well.

Comment: Why do you need this map? It is not needed and each class is represent by different instantiation of a `Php::Class` template, so you can't create common map of it.

Comment: @MarekR I need this map to refer to its values when other classes need to extend from them, as I've explained this in my question.

Comment: @DecentDabbler this is XY problem. Why do you need refer to this values?

Comment: Note that classes should be registered at module startup anyway. You can create a dedicated registration function (per class), but I don't see any reasons to use any of these maps.

Comment: @MarekR I've tried to explain this to you already and I've also explained in my question. But to reiterate: the PHP-CPP library allows you to let the exported PHP classes extend other exported PHP classes. I use this map to refer to earlier created PHP classes to extends from those (without recreating new instances). Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: @VTT But the template function I'm using basically mimics this registration function you talk about, no? Or is that something completely different? I didn't want to hard-code such a function into the class, to keep the classes cleaner (not concerned with actual registration process).

Comment: Still why do you need `map`! Do you intend find class by its name? No I don't think you need this. If you are adding items manually to map to perform registration, you can just register them immediately one by one. Or you can try use initialization of global variables to enforce magic auto registration, like for example gtest registers tests.

Comment: @MarekR "Do you intend find class by its name?" Yes! That's exactly it! :) I mean, finding them by their class name/type would be great too, but this was the simplest I could think of, with my limited knowledge of C++. I kind of register them all at once already, inside of `get_module()`, but the whole point is to make `get_module()` less cluttered. And I don't want to use globals, particularly since [PHP-CPP documentation](http://www.php-cpp.com/documentation/extension-callbacks) advices against this.

Comment: If you want to "keep the classes cleaner" then you probably should not use PHP-CPP at all since it produces quite a code bloat. Php actually performs class registration on per-class basis rather then "method by method" as implemented in PHP-CPP.

Comment: I'm still thinking that this is [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You should register class and don't do anything else it should be reachable from PHP. If you are trying find class by name in C++ layer this means that you are doing something wrong or your requirements are strange. If this is the case than this is your X problem to solve.

Comment: @MarekR I appreciate you looking into this, but I don't think it's an XY problem. The PHP-CPP library requires me to register all functions, classes, interfaces, methods and class inheritances, that I actually want to export to PHP, to the extension. The documentation show examples where this is all done inside the `get_module()`, but as stated before, this could get very cluttered. So I try to do this inside the individual class files, where I define them. So, I need this `classMap` of `Php::Class<whatever>` "objects" so that I can extend from them at the appropriate place.

Comment: @VTT You are probably right about the added code bloat, but the added benefit for me, as a total C++/PHP extension beginner, is that it hides away all the Zend complexities, which, at first glance, appears to make it much easier to create a PHP extension.

Comment: You can't use a map of `Php::Class<Something>` to register `OtherThing`, `ThirdThing`. I doubt anything good comes of multiply registering `Something` under different names.

Comment: @Caleth The thing is, all my classes ultimately derive from the same base class, namely `Php::Base` (which is required by PHP-CPP, to allow export to PHP). Surely it must be possible to create a map in which derived instances of the same base class would be allowed, no? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8627889) seems to suggest it *can* be done, by using pointers, but I haven't managed to reproduce this.

Comment: You do not need a collection of objects in your hierarchy, but of *registration objects*. `Php::Class<Base>` is entirely separate from `Php::Class<Derived>`

Comment: @Caleth Yes, that's a really good point actually. But, it's highly likely that those *registration objects* derive from some base type themselves as well, though, no? As the internals of PHP-CPP ultimately probably deal with these objects in some sort of unified way to pass it along to the Zend internals. I've looked at [the source code of PHP-CPP](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-CPP/blob/master/include/class.h#L39), and came to `Php::ClassBase`, but that doesn't seem to work either. How could I determine the actual base type of `Php::Class<whatever>`, if any such exists?

Comment: See the edit to my answer. A much simpler registration object is `std::function<void(Php::Namespace &)>`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Php::Class` is a template, so you *can't* have it as the `mapped_type` of a `std::map`, it *isn't* a type.

You are going to have to have a "register me" function for each class you are registering, that goes into a collection.

```
void registerMammal(Php::Namespace & ns) override 
{ 
    Php::Class<Animal::Mammal> cls("Mammal");

    cls.method<&Animal::Mammal::method>("method");
    // ... 

    ns.add(std::move(cls));
}

std::vector<std::function<void(Php::Extension &, Php::Namespace &)>> AnimalRegistrations{ registerMammal, ... }; 

PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module() {
    static Php::Extension extension( "animals", "0.1" );

    Php::Namespace ns( "Animal" );

    for (auto & reg : AnimalRegistrations)
    {
        reg(ns);
    }

    extension.add( std::move( ns ) );

    return extension;
}
```

If you have loads of namespaces to register, you may end up with a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::function<void(Php::Namespace &)>>>`, matching names to that namespaces collection of registration functions.

You'd use that like

```
Php::Extension extension( "dabbler", "0.1" );

for (auto & pair : NamespaceMap)
{
    Php::Namespace ns(pair.first);
    for (auto & reg : pair.second)
    {
        reg(ns);
    }
    extension.add( std::move( ns ) );
}
```

Comment: I need some time to digest your answer, because I kind of understand what you are suggesting, but not to its full extent. However, I think you probably nailed the issue: `Php::Class` is a template and not a type. Now, are you saying that there is no way to retrieve the actual template from the map again, or are you just saying that I can't access any members of the template. I'm completely fine with the latter, but the former would defeat my intended purpose. Thanks.

Comment: @DecentDabbler I'm saying that a template is not a type. An *instantiation* of a template class is a type. `Php::Class` is a template, `Php::Class<Mammal>` is a class. You can have `std::map<std::string, Php::Class<Mammal>>`, because both type parameters have been filled with types. You can't have `std::map<std::string, Php::Class>`, because the second parameter is a template. You can also have `template<typename T> using ClassMap = std::map<std::string, Php::Class<T>>;`, which makes `ClassMap` a template, but you still can't add a `Php::Class<Dog>` to a `ClassMap<Mammal>`

Comment: Okay, now I'm properly confused. I think I just have to give up on C++, because it's just way too complex for me. I mean, I think I've already tried (combinations of) what you suggest in your comment, but that gave me all sorts of errors about `operator= not being defined`, and `use of deleted function`, etc. I tried it with concrete types (my ideal goal was actually a generic base type), like you suggest (only adding `Php::Class<Mammal>` for instance) and with or without pointers and references, but nothing works. Thanks for your time though; I appreciate it.

Comment: I've decided to give another shot, today. Would you mind reviewing the addendum I have added at the top of my question? I've tried to simplify as much as possible the main issue I'm having. Thanks.

Comment: I see what you are doing, but the whole point of my exercise was to pass along a map of other registration object instances that the current registration object needs to derive from, e.g.: `Php::Class<Mammal> mammal("Mammal"); Php::Class<Dog> dog("Dog"); dog.extends(mammal);`. I know it's convoluted, but that is how PHP-CPP requires me to extend exported PHP classes. I see no other way, if I don't want to create separate instances of the same registration objects, while still decentralizing these procedures out of `get_module()`.

Comment: Oh that's hideous

Comment: What, my intended solution, or PHP-CPP's internals? (Or both? :) )

Comment: PHP-CPP. There must be a way to get a previously registered class back out. I find that documentation entirely lacking. It doesn't list the members of these types, just uses some (or all?) in examples

Comment: "There must be a way to get a previously registered class back out." Exactly! That's what I would have expected as well, but I haven't found a way (could very well be due to my lack of C++ experience, as well).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after lots of trial and error, I've finally managed to put a concrete result of the template `Php::Class` into a map and retrieve it as well:

```
std::map<std::string, Php::Class<Animal::Mammal>> classMap;

Php::Class<Animal::Mammal> mammal( "Mammal" );

classMap.insert( std::make_pair( "Animal::Mammal", mammal ) );

Php::Class<Animal::Mammal> mammal = classMap.at( "Animal::Mammal" );
```

I still don't understand why putting in into the map with:

```
classMap[ "Animal::Mammal" ] = mammal;
```

and retrieving it again with:

```
Php::Class<Animal::Mammal> mammal = classMap[ "Animal::Mammal" ];
```

wouldn't work, though. If someone could enlighten me about these intricacies, I'd appreciate it.

I presume it has something to do with the error messages I've shown in my question, about operators not being defined. I would have expected there to be some default behavior though, if operators are not explicitly defined, but it appears this is not the case.

Comment: The main reason that `[]` fails and `at` succeeds is that `[]` requires the type be default constructable (i.e. no parameters constructor), `=` fails because the type is explicitly blocked from being copied. That's why the examples are using `std::move`

Comment: @Caleth Thanks. I really appreciate you taking the time to elaborate on these things. But, my god, C++ is complicated! :) I really have to digest your comment once more. :)

Comment: There's a good reason for that rule. `[]` will add a *new value* into the map if the key isn't found. `map["key"] = value` does a default construction and then an assignment. `at` just throws if the key is not found.

Comment: @Caleth Okay, so are you saying `classMap[ "Animal::Mammal" ] = mammal;` creates a new instance (a clone perhaps?) of `Php::Class<Animal::Mammal>`. Because that surely wasn't my intention. I would preferably just like to put the original instance into the map (a reference, or a pointer then perhaps?). That was my whole purpose of the map to begin with. :) To pass around original instances in a map, in stead of creating new ones inside each `addToExtension()` function. (For retrieval, since we both concluded that that's impossible from the PHP-CPP containers themselves, right now).

Comment: The `[]` simply can't exist for `std::map<..., Php::Class<...>>`. Other members do, like `insert`, `emplace` and `at`. And don't worry about "original instances". An object in C++ **is** the memory that it occupies. If you have an object local to a function, and want it elsewhere, there has to be two objects for as least as long as the transfer of contents.

Comment: @Caleth So then my whole exercise was futile? I could just as well create a new instance inside `addToExtension()`, instead of passing around a map of earlier created *registration objects*? I thought one could pass around objects by reference in C++? (Which I interpret to mean it refers to the exact same instance and any change made to the reference is reflected in the original instance).

Comment: What I mean is a `std::map<..., Php::Class<...>>` has some memory allocated somewhere for each `Php::Class<...>` object. When you `move` a value into the map, it creates it, in the the location the map allocated, by "stealing" the contents of the function-local object. Then the function returns and the function-local object ceases to exist.

Comment: @Caleth Right! Understood. But would there be a way for me to add references into the map, instead of `move`ing or the way I have gotten it to work at the moment?

Comment: You can safely create a pointed-to `Php::Class<...>` and pass the pointer to a `std::map<..., std::unique_ptr<Php::Class<...>>>`, but if you just had a map of references, they would be referring to objects that no longer exist. (You also can't have a map of references directly, only of `std::reference_wrapper<...>`, mainly because you can't change which object is referred to by a reference.)

Comment: @Caleth But surely the objects would keep existing for the duration of the `get_module()` function, right? So if I do `get_module() { create objects; put references to objects in map; call addToExtension( ext, ns, map ) multiple times; do some other stuff; }`. Surely the objects will keep existing for as long as I haven't exited the `get_module()` yet, no? Since `addToExtension()` are all called from within `get_module()`, synchronously? Or am I lacking basic knowledge of C++ here? Is it not synchronous at all, perhaps?

Comment: If `create objects;` is a `void` function call, no. The locals to *that function* have ceased to exist when it returns. If it's a bunch of `auto var = create<Php::Class<...>>()` functions, it's a bit more complex. The language pretends that there is a separate object that is moved into `var`, but the actual behaviour is that the location of `var` is passed into the function, and `var` is constructed in the call.

Comment: That's what I mean by "don't worry about original instances". Lumps of memory are relatively interchangeable

Comment: @Caleth O, wait, you're right of course. I totally forgot that I wanted to add objects into the map from within `addToExtension()`. But you're telling me they cease to exist after `addToExtension()` returns. That makes sense. Unless I use `new`, right? But I read that *that* calls for intricate memory management (needing `delete` and all). It's starting to make more sense now. I think I'll just try without the map and create the objects locally inside `addToExtension()`, when needed, and see where that gets me. Thanks so far for your time and patience. You've been really helpful!

Comment: And I don't think I'm even allowed to use `new` with the `Php::Class` template, if I recall earlier attempts correctly.

Comment: Importantly, *an* object with the values you setup exists. It's just generally not necessary to care whether it is *the same* object or just an equal one

Comment: @Caleth Right, but surely there must be numerous occasions in C++ where you want to be sure you are always acting on the same instance, no? For the sake of data consistency/integrity. Or is that just a matter of carefully moving (copies of) objects around? Let's say `BankAccount.withdraw( 100, otherBackAccount );` is called in different scopes (and for argument's sake let's pretend there's no database backend, just an in memory balance), wouldn't it be wise to make sure you're always acting on the same instance for the consistency/integrity of the balance? (Sorry for the poor example. :))

Comment: That's what move-only types are for. You know that there is only one object *with that value* at any given time.